# Jenkins fail to create log directory

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins creates 'log' file in build directory, but my Rails app includes 'log' directory, so Jenkins fails to create log directory since build directory include log file.

Is there any way to change name of log file or any other solution?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you storing your rails code in a source code repository like SUbversion or GIT? Normally a Jenkins job will pull the code down and place it in a workspace directory. This is the space dedicated to your application.

Comment: I found that I've not set Rcov report directory. Therefore Jenkins tries to copy entire Rails app directory and cause error. Thanks for your help.